# Phonegap iFrame on Android 2.2

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

THis is a issue i've on andorid 2.x ~, on 4.x seems to work fine.

I've this application that inside has an iframe.

The content seems to load fine and don't have problems with it.

The big issue i been trying to fix since last wensday is that the iframe ignores the size i wrote on the html, and just uses one to fit the content of the iframe content; and that makes the phonegap webview stretch to iframe new width.

Will try to explain in the best i can: A phone with lets say a resolution of: 320*640 The iframe content takes 760*400~ The iframe goes off screen, wich is fine i don't want to scale it or anything different, but it results that on 2.n because the iframe width is the 'content' width i can't scroll to see the rest of the iframe content so

the iframe:

```
 <iframe id="remoteFrame" src="'+remote_url+'" scrolling="yes" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
```

Any ideas? Anyone else experienced this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trouble is not the phonegap itself. Android 2.X not works fine with iframe. I already tried a lot of "solutions".

What you can do is use a plugin to open a second browser: https://github.com/purplecabbage/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/ChildBrowser or send user to default browser.

Comment: You can use Cordova's inAppBrowser which is a core plugin if you are worried about maintainability.

Comment: can InAppBrowwer work in fullscreen mode? my app is in fullscreen but when I switch to InAppBrowser the fullscreen is lost...

Comment: I belive you can use in fullscreen, maybe you need to change the java file, I'm not sure. Try to open a issue in github project.